# Cannot retrieve data from external json out put

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsonp

```
       $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php",
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {

            var markup = "";
            $.each(data.list, function(i, elem) {
                var $template = $('<div><li><img class="ui-li-icon profile"><p class="from"></p><p class="tweet"></p></li></div>');
                $template.find(".from").append(elem['p_name']);


            });


        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action

        }
    });

});



      <?php

$mysqli_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'nature_secret');
$query = 'select nature_secret.tbl_product.p_name from tbl_product';
$stmt = $mysqli_connect->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($productName);

$json = array();
$json['list'] = array();
$subJSON = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $subJSON['p_name'] = $productName;
    array_push($json['list'], $subJSON);
}
$json_encode = json_encode($json);
echo $json_encode;

?>
```

I used above code to run to retrieve from localhost Server.In order to run the retrieve data from another server i add following code snippet 
    **jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',**.When i add that part code is not working

Comment: did you modify your server side code accordingly to wrap the jsondata inside the callback function? Meaning, the server has to return a javascript function call for the jsonp to work.

Comment: Because you are specifying a `jsonCallback`, this function needs to exist. Try declaring a `function jsonCallback(data) { console.log(data); } `